# Increase screen dim tim in linux mint

Tags: display, linux-mint

I have just installed Linux Mint 13, Want to watch a movie on it but after 10 seconds my screen goes dim. How can I disable that dim feature or can increase the time from 10 seconds to more?

I am very new to Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the MATE edition? Check [How to customize power management in Linux Mint 13 - MATE](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/07/how-to-customize-power-management-in.html).